# How to write xpath for datatable with lazy loading to fetch total number of rows using selinium

Tags: java, html

I am not able to get the xpath for data table with lazy loading to count number of rows

```
<div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 369px; min-height: 0px;">
<table id="offers_table" class="display article-list ranklist_drag table table-bordered dataTable no-footer" aria-describedby="offers_table_info" role="grid" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<tr class="even" role="row">
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<tr class="even" role="row">
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<tr class="even" role="row">
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<tr class="even" role="row">
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<tr class="even" role="row">
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<tr class="even" role="row">
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<tr class="even" role="row">
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<tr class="even" role="row">
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<tr class="even" role="row">
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<tr class="even" role="row">
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image: class]

regards,
Apurva

Answer (score 0):

to count rows in table:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#offers_table tbody tr[role='row']")).size()
```

or xpath:

```
String xpath = By.xPath("//table[@id='offers_table']//tbody//tr[@role='row']");
driver.findElements(xpath).size()
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[@id='offers_table']//tbody//tr[@role='row']"}

Comment: locator is correct if you provided correct id of the table and @role attribute) Are you sure table is present on the page when driver starts looking for it?

Comment: yes table is present on the same page ,but its not able to locate

Comment: are you sure table is not in iframe? i can't help more not seeing the real html

Comment: Its not in iframe